# Make compass in React-Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, reactjs

I'am trying to make a compass but i don't know how to use the data of the Magnetometer.

This is my class Compass:

```
class Compass extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  componentWillMount(){
    this._animeRotation = new Animated.Value(0);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
      this.startAnimation();
  }
  startAnimation() {
    Animated.timing(this._animeRotation, {
      toValue: this.props.magn, //<-- What put here?
      duration: 1000,
    }).start(() => {
      this.startAnimation();
    });
  }
  render() {
    var interpolatedRotateAnimation = this._animeRotation.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 100],
      outputRange: ['0deg', '360deg']
    });
    return (
      <View>
        <Animated.View style={[styles.box, {transform: [{rotate: interpolatedRotateAnimation}]}]}>
          <Image style={styles.box} source={require('./arrow.png')}></Image>
        </Animated.View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

This is the class App:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      magn: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        z: 0
      }
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    //I can get the gyroscope if is necessary
    SensorManager.startMagnetometer(500);
    // magn is a object with axis z,y and x
    DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('Magnetometer', (magn) => this.setState({magn})); 
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
          <Compass magn={this.state.magn.x}></Compass>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

With this code the arrow rotate but not as it should. That I have to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The numbers are just relative to currently detected "magnetic north" which is affected by any material with iron (like steel) in the building. So you first have to determine what the true north is.

Also you need to use the X, Y, and Z and get the direction relative to the phone (if it's held horizontally or vertically and which way portrait or landscape). The algorithm is not simple at all.

For this reason, I suggest you use existing packages for getting the direction instead of the Sensor data package. They do the calculations and give you a number with the heading like you seem to be expecting in your animation code. Another possibility is to look into the open source code of these packages and copy the calculations.

If your React Native app is with Expo, like if it was made with the `Create React Native App` command (CRNA) then you can use `Expo Location`. Here's [an example](https://github.com/martincarrera/expo-location-example on Github) and [here are the docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/location) (look for the Heading section).

Otherwise, you can use the [React Native simple compass](https://github.com/vnil/react-native-simple-compass)

Comment: I haven’t been able to find a compass package that works in landscape mode, specifically on Android. If you know of one could you please share it with me?

Answer (score 2):

I ended up making my own package. check it out:

https://github.com/firofame/react-native-compass-heading

Comment: Nice! Does this work with react-native 0.60? What are the known bugs?

Comment: @TIMEX I am using it in my app with react-naive 0.60.5. There aren't any known bugs as of now, feel free to add an issue if you find any.

Comment: Its lagging a lot from pixel 2

Comment: This package lags a lot. Don't get the smooth experience.